# Progress Bar in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm really trying to add a upload progress bar using Jquery to the following script. I'm quite new to JS so if anyone has any ideas or tutorials, that would be great.

Thanks.

```
    $('.buttonStyle2').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#upload').slideDown();
        $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    });
    $('#form-add .submit_form').click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: "JSON",
                  url: '<?php echo $this->url('video/add_video')?>?key='+$('#video_key').val()+'&title='+$('#title').val()+'&description='+$('#description').val(),
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(typeof data !== "undefined" && data) {
                        if(data.id > 0) {
                            window.location.replace('<?php echo BASE_URL.$this->url('rate_my_swing');?>?video='+data.id);
                        } else {
                            $('.videoTabArea .error').show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('.videoTabArea .error').show();
                    }
                  }
            });
    });
});
function setGUID(id) {
    $('#form-iframe').hide();
    $('#video_key').val(id);
    $('#form-add').show();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The jQuery progress bar can only display the progress of actions that you can track. Currently, it is not very easy to track the progress of a file upload without using either long-polling ajax requests or socket-based pushing such as pusher.com, both of which are overkill considering that most uploads happen very quickly anyway unless you are uploading files larger than 10mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with this: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/